# UIWebView: Tracking screen updates (dirty regions)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiwebview, calayer

I'm trying to detect animations and other screen updates as they happen inside a UIWebView. I would like to get the rectangles of areas in the UIWebView that have been modified since the last refresh.

I think really what I'm looking for is for a way to "trap" the calls that UIWebView makes to setNeedsDisplayInRect. Is there a way to do that? Can I somehow subclass UIWebView's underlying CALayer object in a way that would allow me to catch those calls as they come in from UIWebView?

Comment: Just an update: I've tried to use an Objective C category (@implementation CALayer (MyCALayer)) to trap calls going from UIWebView into its CALayer. I am getting the calls, including setNeedsDisplayInRect, but it looks like there is no way to process the calls and then relay them to the original CALayer object. What am I missing? Surely there's a way to do this?

Comment: I'd also like to know if this is possible!

Comment: I really need an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way of doing that. You can try grabbing a snapshot of the UIWebView's CALayer and comparing it to the previous snapshot, but I've had a lot of trouble getting reliable snapshots of UIWebViews.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Objective-C category (@implementation CALayer (MyCALayer)) - like you're already doing based on your update - to trap the calls going from UIWebView to CALayer.

Then, use [Method Swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling) to relay your category overrides to the original CALayer object.

Comment: The problem with this is you're doing it to every CALayer. The UIWebView's layer can be overridden with `+ (Class)layerClass`. But the layer actually being changed is inside a private sub-view.